# how can we increase button long click listener time in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

i want to execute simple click listener as well as long click listener on same button. But i need to execute long click listener after 5 seconds delay 
in the longclicklistener executes after 1 seconds of hold .so using handler it will executes after 5 seocnds.but i need exact to press button for 5 seconds then code to executes ...

Comment: what you done share code

Comment: here is my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Handler` like this way:

```
Button b=findViewById(R.id.btn);

    final Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Your code to run on long click

        }
    };
    final Handler handel = new Handler();
    b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            switch (arg1.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    handel.postDelayed(run, 5000/* OR the amount of time you want */);
                    break;

                default:
                    handel.removeCallbacks(run);
                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: you need to press button 5second then after you will show the toast, it's work for me

Comment: Hey remove img_one.setOnClickLick and img_one.setOnLongClickListener

Comment: only put single setOnTouchListener in code remove other Listener and check it

Comment: i didnt use  img_one.setOnClickLick and img_one.setOnLongClickListener

Comment: check name in upside  ->updated code for AD10

code is below that name

Comment: i i check it not understand what is problem at your side, my side it's work perfectly, thank for the post code, now you can remove

Comment: hey did you find the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change the timer on the onLongClick event, it is managed by android itself.

What is possible is to use .setOnTouchListener().

Then register when the MotionEvent is a ACTION_DOWN.
Note the current time in a variable.
Then when a MotionEvent with ACTION_UP is registered and the current_time - actionDown time > 5000 ms then do something.

so pretty much:

```
Button button = new Button();
long then = 0;
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                then = (Long) System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(((Long) System.currentTimeMillis() - then) > 5000){
                    // 5 second of long click
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Comment: i tried this also but  i want result when button continues press for 5 seconds and then code executes . not when button Action Up